# Jest - Testing for AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, jestjs

I'm trying to use Jest with my NodeJS based AWS Lambda function to test that the Lambda handler function is returning specific status codes. It seems like using [lambda-tester](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lambda-tester) is the easiest way to achieve this.

**handler.test.js**

```
const handler = require('../src/handler.js');
const LambdaTester = require('lambda-tester');

test('should return a StatusCode of 400 due to requirement not being met', function (done) {
  return LambdaTester(handler.run)
    .event({})
    .expectResult(result => {
      expect(result.statusCode).toBe(400);
    });
});
```

I thought that would be pretty straightforward however I get this as a result:

```
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

Expected: 400
Received: 500

   7 |     .event({})
   8 |     .expectResult(result => {
>  9 |       expect(result.statusCode).toBe(400);
     |                                 ^
  10 |     });
  11 | });
  12 | 

  at tests/handler.test.js:9:33
  at runVerifier (node_modules/lambda-tester/lib/runner.js:121:16)
  at LambdaRunner.run (node_modules/lambda-tester/lib/runner.js:277:23)
```

If I change the expect line to check for a statuscode of 500 I get an Async timeout:

> Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout
>   specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout

Any ideas as to why this isn't working?

The lambda should fail instantly because the event being passed in doesnt have a required attribute and it indeed does when tested via Postman.

**Edit:**
This lambda is part of a serverless application and could be tested locally, how could I use Jest to do that?

Comment: 1) have you tried with `await`? 2) do you really need to test it in aws environment (e.g.: your lambda depends on other lambdas to work) or could you just abstract the functionality to test it locally?

Answer (score 0):

I was over thinking it, the below is working well:

```
test('should return a StatusCode of 400 due to requirement not being met', async () => {

  const event = {};
  const context = {};

  const result = await handler.run(event, context);
  expect(result.statusCode).toBe(400)
  expect(result.headers)

});
```